# HTML email not rendering correctly when Outlook user views in IE browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer, outlook, html-email

I've built a responsive email using conditional statements for Outlook (making it not responsive in Outlook). It is looking fine in all email clients but when an Outlook user chooses to view the email in a browser (Outlook auto opens IE, I have IE10), it appears to be zoomed in at like 50000%. I build responsive emails all the time and have never experienced this issue. The only difference with this one is that most of the content is dynamically pulled from a DB. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Here is the doctype and head code from the email if it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0" />
<title>Untitled</title>

    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <style type="text/css">
            .noOutlook { display:none; }
            #outlook {display: block;}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: If you remove the meta viewport line does that make a difference?

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing I tried, but no difference.

Comment: View source of the page in IE. Is there any html/css causing the stretching of the body/wrapper size? If you copy the URL into Chrome/FF, does it do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what was causing this but using conditional statements for IE8 and up I was able to set the width and fix the issue.